# Set schema in pyspark dataframe read.csv with null elements

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data set (example) that when imported with

```
df = spark.read.csv(filename, header=True, inferSchema=True)
df.show()
```

will assign the column with 'NA' as a stringType(), where I would like it to be IntegerType() (or ByteType()).

[image: inferSchema]

I then tried to set

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("col_01", IntegerType()),
    StructField("col_02", DateType()),
    StructField("col_03", IntegerType())
])
df = spark.read.csv(filename, header=True, schema=schema)
df.show()
```

The output shows the entire row with *'col_03' = null* to be null.

[image: entire_row_null]

However *col_01* and *col_02* return appropriate data if they are called with

```
df.select(['col_01','col_02']).show()
```

[image: row_actually_not_null]

I can find a way around this by post casting the data type of *col_3*

```
df = spark.read.csv(filename, header=True, inferSchema=True)
df = df.withColumn('col_3',df['col_3'].cast(IntegerType()))
df.show()
```

[image: import_then_cast]

, but I think it is not ideal and would be much better if I can assign the data type for each column directly with setting schema.

Would anyone be able to guide me what I do incorrectly? Or casting the data types after importing is the only solution? Any comment regarding performance of the two approaches (if we can make assigning schema to work) is also welcome.

Thank you,

Comment: Does the behaviour change when your schema explicitly specify `True or Fase` for nulls as in  `StructField("col_03", IntegerType(), True)`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, the behavior still persists.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set a new null value in spark's csv loader using `nullValue`:

for a csv file looking like this:

```py
col_01,col_02,col_03
111,2007-11-18,3
112,2002-12-03,4
113,2007-02-14,5
114,2003-04-16,NA
115,2011-08-24,2
116,2003-05-03,3
117,2001-06-11,4
118,2004-05-06,NA
119,2012-03-25,5
120,2006-10-13,4
```

and forcing schema:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, IntegerType, DateType

schema = StructType([
    StructField("col_01", IntegerType()),
    StructField("col_02", DateType()),
    StructField("col_03", IntegerType())
])
```

You'll get:

```py
df = spark.read.csv(filename, header=True, nullValue='NA', schema=schema)
df.show()
df.printSchema()

    +------+----------+------+
    |col_01|    col_02|col_03|
    +------+----------+------+
    |   111|2007-11-18|     3|
    |   112|2002-12-03|     4|
    |   113|2007-02-14|     5|
    |   114|2003-04-16|  null|
    |   115|2011-08-24|     2|
    |   116|2003-05-03|     3|
    |   117|2001-06-11|     4|
    |   118|2004-05-06|  null|
    |   119|2012-03-25|     5|
    |   120|2006-10-13|     4|
    +------+----------+------+

    root
     |-- col_01: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- col_02: date (nullable = true)
     |-- col_03: integer (nullable = true)
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this once - (But this will read every column as string type. You can type caste as per your requirement)

```
import csv
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

data = []
with open('filename', 'r' ) as doc:
    reader = csv.DictReader(doc)
    for line in reader:
        data.append(line)

df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF()
df = df.withColumn("col_03", df["col_03"].cast(IntegerType()))
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I think it not different from my work-around solution though. Since both approaches read the data first and then cast the type. I am looking for a way that allows casting before reading the data and not giving the weird behavior.