# How to change the data type of the columns of a PySpark dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a `dataframe` where all the columns are of type `string` and I need them to be of type `double`. I have code that does it:

```
df_Double = df.select([df[c].cast(DoubleType()).alias(c) for c in df.columns]
```

The problem is that when I save this new dataframe in memory

```
df_Double.drop("_c0").toPandas().to_csv("all_Double.csv", header = "true")
```

and I read it again

```
df_Double = spark.read \
    .format("csv") \
    .option("inferSchema",True) \
    .option("header", True) \
    .load("all_Double.csv")
```

and show your schema

```
df_Double.printSchema()
```

all columns are of type `string` like the original `dataframe`. How can I make the change to be saved in memory and not have to change the data type every time I read the `dataframe`?

Comment: CSV is a very basic format and does not contain any datatypes, only text. So there is no difference between "3.1415" as a string and "3.1415" as a double. Either use a "better" format when exporting (like parquet) or specify the schema when you read the csv.

Comment: How can I specify the schema when reading the csv?

Comment: Do you have data like `null,null` in column instead of `,` (empty string for null value) or `NaN,NaN`?   Assuming all other values are double value, by using `inferSchema=True`, the first data cannot auto cast to Double whereas second and third data would cast.

Comment: If you want to enforce the schema, you can pass it with `.schema(yourschema)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use df_Double.schema when you bring the csv file

```
df_Double_load = spark.read \
.format("csv") \
.schema(df_Double.schema) \
.option("header", True) \
.load("all_Double.csv")
```

you shouldn't use the option 'inferSchema' because this option allow spark to set schema automatically.
So don't use that option.

Comment: How can I apply that solution if when I read the csv for the first time there is no `df_Double`?

Comment: In that case, you should assign datatypes about `df_Double`. 
There is a perfect solution. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48698062/set-schema-in-pyspark-dataframe-read-csv-with-null-elements)  

Or if you want spark assign datatypes automatically, put `.option("inferSchema",True)`